# How to do bidirectional sync between Android SQLite and SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sqlite, synchronization

Hello, I want to know if there is any way to synchronize my SQLite database in Android to a SQL Server database in the main server in an automated way.

I'm new to Android development and I've been using SQL Server replication in the past with my Windows Mobile apps which provides me a lot of features like conflict detection and resolution. I want to know if there's something similar to SQL Server replication in Android or something like that.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e and my android implementation (not finished) http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/

Comment: I end up using your example with sync framework. it was very helpful

Comment: Is this still the best way to do it in 2015?

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done easily. There is, however, an alternative storage method like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) which provides automatic synchronization with multiple other databases.